# How to test a public Google Workspace Marketplace web app before submitting for review?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, service-accounts, google-apps-marketplace

I have a web app to be listed in the google workspace marketplace. I have a list of scopes that is needed to solve my use case. I have the dev version as a private app which uses the service account, tested all the functionalities and made sure everything is working fine.

Now how do I test how the flow is going to look like for the public app? I understand if someone from my own domain installs the app, I will be able to get the data but the public flow through the service account is still unclear for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your add-on with a limited list of defined external users.

To do that, you must set the `User type` as `External > Testing` within the Oauth consent screen settings in Google Cloud Console.

Keep in mind that only the users defined in the settings will be able to test the app however.

You may find more information [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-workspace-addons) and [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615#zippy=%2Cexternal%2Ctesting)

Comment: The links you provided (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-workspace-addons) premises that the app is in the form of add-on. How about when the app is in the form of web-app only?